# Returning the index of the n-th highest value of an unsorted list

Tags: java, arrays, list, search, indexing

I have written the following code and am now trying to figure out the best way to achieve what is explained in the four comments:

```
    Integer[] expectedValues = new Integer[4];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        expectedValues[i] = getExpectedValue(i);
    }

    int choice = randomNumGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if (choice <= intelligence) {
        // return index of highest value in expectedValues
    } else if (choice <= intelligence * 2) {
        // return index of 2nd highest value in expectedValues
    } else if (choice <= intelligence * 3) {
        // return index of 3rd highest value in expectedValues
    } else {
        // return index of lowest value in expectedValues
    }
```

What would be an elegant way o doing so? I do not need to keep expected values as an array - I am happy to use any data structure.

Comment: @assylias In this case the indices of the array aren't just indices. `getExpectedValues(i)` is getting specific values needed for `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and I then need to return the INDEX of the array with the n-th highest value, not return the value itself.

Comment: @nvioli `getExpectedValue()` can only ever take either `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` as a parameter, and so the loop is just there to calculate these 4 values. If, for example, the function instead could only take `6`, `7`, `8`, or `9` as parameters, then my loop would be `for (int i = 6; i <= 9; i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new array containing the indices and sort on the values - in semi-pseudo code it could look like this (to be adapted):

```
int[][] valueAndIndex = new int[n][2];

//fill array:
valueAndIndex[i][0] = i;
valueAndIndex[i][1] = expectedValues[i];

//sort on values in descending order
Arrays.sort(valueAndIndex, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(b[1], a[1]));

//find n-th index
int n = 3; //3rd largest number
int index = valueAndIndex[n - 1][0];
```

Comment: This works, but is a little bit messy. Perhaps a `Map<Integer, Integer>` would be cleaner?

Comment: @lucasvw my initial thought was to use a map, but I would eventually have to return the a key retrieved using a value - the opposite way a map is intended to work, and so this would also get quite messy

Comment: @lucasvw with a map, you will need to sort on keys - so the index in the array will be the values in the map and the values in the array will be the keys, which may lead to collisions if there are equal values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with simple arrays, maybe this might be a solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 4, 2, 3 };
    int[] sorted = sortedCopy(arr);

    int choice = randomNumGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if (choice <= intelligence) {
        System.out.println(findIndex(arr, sorted[3])); // 1
    } else if (choice <= intelligence * 2) {
        System.out.println(findIndex(arr, sorted[2])); // 3
    } else if (choice <= intelligence * 3) {
        System.out.println(findIndex(arr, sorted[1])); // 2
    } else {
        System.out.println(findIndex(arr, sorted[0])); // 0
    }
}

static int[] sortedCopy(int[] arr) {
    int[] copy = new int[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, copy, 0, arr.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return copy;
}

static int findIndex(int[] arr, int val) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == val) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: `int[] copy = new int[arr.length]; System.arraycopy(arr, 0, copy, 0, arr.length);` can be written more simply:  `int[] copy = arr.clone();`

Answer (score 0):

You can "wipe out" the highest value n-1 times. After this the highest value is the n-th highest value of the original array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[]{5, 9, 1, 4};
    int n = 2; // n-th index

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        int maxIndex = findMaxIndex(numbers);
        numbers[maxIndex] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    int maxIndex = findMaxIndex(numbers);
    System.out.println(maxIndex + " -> " + numbers[maxIndex]);
}

public static int findMaxIndex(int[] numbers) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < numbers.length; ++j) {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = j;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

The complexity is `O(n * numbers.length)`.